# Deserialize a XML list of fix values

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

Given the following XML:

```xml
<Values>
  <Value ID="Foo">foo</Value>
  <Value ID="Bar">42</Value>
</Values>
```

The list of IDs is always the same.
How can I parse this into the following class using the serializer attributes?

```cs
public class Values {
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

---

It's very easy to just parse it as array, but that makes it very cumbersome to validate the values or read them.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Values
{
    [XmlElement("Values")]
    public Value[]? Values { get; init; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Value
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string? Id { get; init; }

    [XmlText]
    public string? Value { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: One possibility is to have two different classes representing `Values` (e.g. `Values` and `SerializableValues`), and map between them with a custom mapping class.

Comment: You say "parse this into the following class" which is *deserializing* and not *serializing*.

Comment: Does this answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: @Natrium how this could be duplicate ? OP provide what is working and what he really wants

Comment: @Jakube seems like you need to build custom deserialize fx by implementing IXmlSerializable

Comment: [Value2 is slightly faster with primitives/strings and twice faster if value is custom type(like Kung in this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Agrae4)